# Polymorphic deserialization gson

Tags: java, gson

I have a `Vehicle` interface which `Car` and `Bus` implement. The server returns a response like this -

```
{
    "id" : 10,
    "vehicle_type" : "Car",
    "vehicle" : {
          "id"  : 100,
          "name" : "MyCar"
    }
    // More attributes.
}
```

The corresponding class to model it is

```
class Response {
    int id;
    String vehicle_type;
    Vehicle vehicle;
    // More attributes.
}
```

The `vehicle_type` in the `response` declares what kind of vehicle it is. I need to deserialize the `response` into a `Response` object depending on the `vehicle_type`. If it is `Car` I need to use `Car.class` for deserializing `vehicle` during the deserialization of `response` and `Bus.class` if it is otherwise.

How can I achieve this using gson?

EDIT - [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21767485/gson-deserialization-to-specific-object-type-based-on-field-value) post is different in the sense that class type(`type`) is contained within the `jsonobject` that needs to deserialized. Here it is not. If `vehicle_type` was inside `vehicle`, I could write a custom deserializer for `Vehicle`, check the `vehicle_type` and deserialize accordingly. But I think I would need to write a custom deserializer for `Response` where I create a new `Response` object, parse `vehicle_type`, deserialize it into a `Vehicle` object accordingly and add it and rest of attributes of `response` to the `Response` object manually by parsing them. This is very cumbersome and using gson doesn't really help then. I was hoping for a better solution. :)

Comment: Have you read this thread?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21767485/gson-deserialization-to-specific-object-type-based-on-field-value

Comment: @Rob I just did. Please check the edit.

Comment: @zack follow the same model as the earlier post for Response and within it use `context.deserialize()` for Car/Bus - you don't need to do it manually. See the comment on the accepted answer.

Comment: @KDM I meant I would have to add the other attributes of `response` to the object manually.

Comment: @zack I don't know much about jackson. This http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18313323/how-do-i-call-the-default-deserializer-from-a-custom-deserializer-in-jackson might help. Something like use default serializer to serialise the Response object and do some more extra work.

Comment: @KDM I ended up doing exactly that. I'll post an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I wrote a custom deserializer for `Response` where I first invoke the default deserializer, get the `vehicle type` and do `Vehicle` deserialization accordingly.

```
public Response deserialize(JsonElement jsonElement, Type type, JsonDeserializationContext jsonDeserializationContext) throws JsonParseException {
    Response response = new Gson().fromJson(jsonElement, Response.class);
    Type t = null;
    if (response.getVehicleType().equals(Bus.vehicle_type)) {
        t = Bus.class;
    } else if (response.getVehicleType().equals(Car.vehicle_type)) {
        t = Car.class;
    }
    JsonObject object = jsonElement.getAsJsonObject();
    if (object.has("vehicle")) {
        JsonElement vehicleElement = object.get("vehicle");
        Vehicle vehicle = jsonDeserializationContext.deserialize(vehicleElement, t);
        response.setVehicle(vehicle);
    }
    return response;
}
```

Looking forward to better solutions. :)