# GSON: JSON deserialization to variable type (List/String)

Tags: java, json, gson, deserialization, retrofit

At this point it's already an old question and I've probably read every related topic on SO.

But to the point. I need some advice or correction maybe?

For some reason we have generatable Jsons of 2 types:

`{"data": {"id": "value"}}` and `{"data":[{"id": "value"}]}`

Object and Array. There are also other params but they doesn't matter here. "id" is differ for every request. Sometimes it's userId, portfolioId etc. So I get "id" and pass it to related var.

For a long time I was working with the first case. And created POJO like this:

**Data.class**

```
public class Data {

@SerializedName("id")
@Expose
private String id;

public Data() {
}

public Data(String id) {
    super();
    this.id = id;
}

protected String getId() {
    return id;
}
```

And I adress "data" paramets via **User.class**.

```
@JsonAdapter(UserDeserializer.class)
public Data data;


public Data getData() {
    return data;
}

public void setData(Data data) {
    this.data = data;
}


public User() {
}

public User(Data data) {
    super();
    this.data = data;
}

Gson gson = new Gson();

public String getPortfolioList(String tokenId, String userId) {
    Call<User> call = apiRequest.getPortfolioList(userId, tokenId);

    try {
        User newResult = gson.fromJson(String.valueOf(call.execute().body()), User.class);
        System.out.println(newResult.getData().getId());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return getPortfolioId();
}
```

**Deserializer.class**

```
 public class UserDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<User> {

    private Type listType = new TypeToken<List<Data>>(){}.getType();

    @Override
    public User deserialize(JsonElement json, Type type, JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {

        User user = new User();
        JsonElement jsonElement;
        if (json.isJsonArray()) {
            jsonElement = json.getAsJsonArray();
            user.data = context.deserialize(jsonElement,listType);
//            user.data = new Gson().fromJson(jsonElement, new TypeToken<List<Data>>() {}.getType());
        } else {
            jsonElement = json.getAsJsonObject();
            user.data = context.deserialize(jsonElement, Data.class);
//            user.setData(new Gson().fromJson(jsonElement, new TypeToken<Data>() {}.getType()));
        }
        return user;
    }
}
```

*Gson builder* in BaseApi class just in case:

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().registerTypeAdapter(UserDeserializer.class, new UserDeserializer()).setLenient().create();
```

Without custom deserialization and Array JSON issue this would work perfectly. But now I have to determine "data" 's exact type I get.

In above case I get `java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to auto.Rest.Data`

I assume I have to create another *Data* class (for example there will be *DataObject* & *DataArray*) and describe every parameter as I did before in *Data.class* to get this work? I think I do something wrong during deserialization but I'm not sure where tbh.

Or am I wrong and it is possible to invoke *Data* as *List* and *Data* as an *Object* of the same class?

I'm working on this for several days already(?) and was thinking about use generics instead of Gson help, yeah, I'm desperate. So any help appreciated.

Comment: `{"data":[{"id": "value"}]}` indicates you could have an array of multiple ids. What would your `Data` instance look like in that case, e.g. for `{"data":[{"id": "1"}, {"id": "2"}]}`?

Comment: `user.data = context.deserialize(jsonElement,listType);` can't work as you're deserializing a `List<Data>` and are trying to assign that to a field of type `Data`. In that case you should do something like `List<Data> dataList = context.deserialize(jsonElement,listType);` first and then get one of the elements from that list (if there are any) and assign it to `user.data`.

Comment: @Thomas It is a list of portfolios like this: `{"data": [{"id":"c87ca3fe85781007869b83f", "template": 0, "publish": false, "publication_at": null, "likes": 0, "liked": false, "comments": 0, "cells": { "data": [ {/*someting else*/}]}}, {/*another portfolio like the same above*/}]}`

I really hope this is understandable to read.

Comment: @Thomas Thank you. I'll try this. Can I first assign it to `user.data` and then `.getId()` from the latter? Or I have to create the same methods for `List<Data>`?

Comment: If `Data` can be deserialized with out-of-the-box mappings then it should be sufficient to just deserialize the array to a list and get the id from the deserialized elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you always have `object` or `one-element array` you can write custom deserialiser as below:

```
class OneOrElementJsonDeserializer<T> implements JsonDeserializer<T> {

    @Override
    public T deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {
        if (json instanceof JsonArray) {
            final JsonArray array = (JsonArray) json;
            final int size = array.size();
            if (size == 0) {
                return null;
            }

            return context.deserialize(array.get(0), typeOfT);
        }

        return context.deserialize(json, typeOfT);
    }
}
```

Your example model after simplification looks like below:

```
class User {

    @JsonAdapter(OneOrElementJsonDeserializer.class)
    private Data data;

    public User() {
    }

    public User(Data data) {
        super();
        this.data = data;
    }

    public Data getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public void setData(Data data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "User{" +
                "data=" + data +
                '}';
    }
}

class Data {

    private String id;

    protected String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Data{" +
                "id='" + id + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Example usage:

```
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;
import com.google.gson.JsonArray;
import com.google.gson.JsonDeserializationContext;
import com.google.gson.JsonDeserializer;
import com.google.gson.JsonElement;
import com.google.gson.JsonParseException;
import com.google.gson.annotations.JsonAdapter;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.lang.reflect.Type;

public class GsonApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        File jsonFile = new File("./resource/test.json").getAbsoluteFile();

        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
                .setPrettyPrinting()
                .create();

        User root = gson.fromJson(new FileReader(jsonFile), User.class);
        System.out.println(root);
    }
}
```

Above code for below `JSON` payload:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "id": "c87ca3fe85781007869b83f"
    }
  ]
}
```

prints:

```
User{data=Data{id='c87ca3fe85781007869b83f'}}
```

And for `object` case `JSON` payload:

```
{
  "data": {
    "id": "c87ca3fe85781007869b83f"
  }
}
```

prints:

```
User{data=Data{id='c87ca3fe85781007869b83f'}}
```

In case your property could contain `JSON object` or `multi-element array` see my answer to this question [Mapping Json Array to Java Models](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55098886/mapping-json-array-to-java-models). There is implemented deserialiser which handle cases like this.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. For a _call_ this works just fine: `User responseBody = call.execute().body();
            System.out.println(responseBody.getData().getId());` (Yeah, no need for asynchronous call in my case)
 For some reason no need in `gson.fromJson();`
This is probably more delicate solution than I tried to achieve in OP.

Answer (score 2):

if there is always one object, just add

**json.getAsJsonArray().get(0);**

```
public class UserDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<User> {

  private Type listType = new TypeToken<List<Data>>(){}.getType();

  @Override
  public User deserialize(JsonElement json, Type type, JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {

    User user = new User();
    JsonElement jsonElement;
    if (json.isJsonArray()) {
      jsonElement = json.getAsJsonArray().get(0);
      user.data = context.deserialize(jsonElement,listType);
//            user.data = new Gson().fromJson(jsonElement, new TypeToken<List<Data>>() {}.getType());
    } else {
      jsonElement = json.getAsJsonObject();
      user.data = context.deserialize(jsonElement, Data.class);
//            user.setData(new Gson().fromJson(jsonElement, new TypeToken<Data>() {}.getType()));
    }
    return user;
  }

}
```

if there are more objects, change field data to the list

```
public class UserDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<User> {

  private Type listType = new TypeToken<List<Data>>(){}.getType();

  @Override
  public User deserialize(JsonElement json, Type type, JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {

    User user = new User();
    JsonElement jsonElement;
    if (json.isJsonArray()) {
      jsonElement = json.getAsJsonArray();
      user.data = context.deserialize(jsonElement,listType);
//            user.data = new Gson().fromJson(jsonElement, new TypeToken<List<Data>>() {}.getType());
    } else {
      jsonElement = json.getAsJsonObject();
      List<Data> data = new ArrayList<Data>();
      data.add(context.deserialize(jsonElement, Data.class)) ;
      user.data = data ;
//            user.setData(new Gson().fromJson(jsonElement, new TypeToken<Data>() {}.getType()));
    }
    return user;
  }

}
```

and change User.class field data to List

```
public List<Data> data;
```

this is a similar topic in kotlin language [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54996915/3046335)

Comment: Based on @Michał Ziober's answer I've made some corrections to get this work `@Override
    public T deserialize(JsonElement json, Type type, JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {

        JsonElement jsonElement;
        if (json.isJsonArray()) {
            jsonElement = json.getAsJsonArray().get(0);
            return context.deserialize(jsonElement,type);
        } else {
            jsonElement = json.getAsJsonObject();
            return context.deserialize(jsonElement, type); //Data.class works aswell
        }
    }`
Thank you for answer.