# Expected a string but was BEGIN_OBJECT I have to return string

Tags: java, gson

**class**

```
 class PrintRequest {
        private String data;
        private String userImageBase64;
        private String organizationImageBase64;
        private String fileBase64;
     //getters and setters
    }
```

**use**
`PrintRequest printRequest = gson.fromJson(request.getBody(), PrintRequest.class);`

**json**

```
{ 
   "data":{ 
      "nazwaDostawcy":"nazwa dostawcy (opis)",
      "nazwa":"Gniazdo przemysłowe, kątowe, 2p+E, 16A, 100...130 V AC, IP 44 ",
      "kod":"val",
      "kodEan":"val",
      "kodWewnrtrzny":"val",
      "cennaNetto":"val"
   },
   "fileBase64":""
}
```

like in topic, I understand why I'm getting this error, but I NEED to return `data` as string. How can I achieve my aim?

thanks for help!

Comment: Your JSON seems to be incomplete.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the easiest way without creating custom gson serialization. Just override toString() method

```
public class PrintRequest {
     private Value data;
     private String userImageBase64;
     private String organizationImageBase64;
     private String fileBase64;
     //getters and setters
}

public class Value {
    String nazwaDostawcy;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Value{" +
            "nazwaDostawcy='" + nazwaDostawcy + '\'' +
            ", nazwa='" + nazwa + '\'' +
            ", kod='" + kod + '\'' +
            ", kodEan='" + kodEan + '\'' +
            ", kodWewnrtrzny='" + kodWewnrtrzny + '\'' +
            ", cennaNetto='" + cennaNetto + '\'' +
            ", kategoria='" + kategoria + '\'' +
            ", opis='" + opis + '\'' +
            ", logo1='" + logo1 + '\'' +
            ", logo2='" + logo2 + '\'' +
            '}';
}

String nazwa;
String kod;
String kodEan;
String kodWewnrtrzny;
String cennaNetto;
String kategoria;
String opis;
String logo1;
String logo2;
//getters and setters
}
```

### Usage:

PrintRequest printRequest = gson.fromJson(json, PrintRequest.class);
 System.out.println(printRequest.getData().toString());

### UPD:

Solution with custom JsonDeserializer

```
public class CustomJsonDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<PrintRequest> {

    @Override
    public PrintRequest deserialize(JsonElement jsonElement, Type type, JsonDeserializationContext jsonDeserializationContext) throws JsonParseException {
        PrintRequest printRequest = new PrintRequest();
        JsonObject jsonObject = jsonElement.getAsJsonObject();
        String dataStr="";
        JsonObject jsonObjectData = jsonObject.getAsJsonObject("data");
        for (Data data : Data.values()) {
            dataStr+=(data.name() + ":" + jsonObjectData.get(data.name()).getAsString()+",\n");
        }
        printRequest.setData(dataStr);
        return printRequest;
    }
}


public enum Data {
    nazwaDostawcy,
    nazwa
}

public class PrintRequest {
    private String data;
    private String userImageBase64;
    private String organizationImageBase64;
    private String fileBase64;
    //getters and setters
```

Usage:

```
GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();
        gsonBuilder.setFieldNamingPolicy(FieldNamingPolicy.LOWER_CASE_WITH_UNDERSCORES);
        gsonBuilder.registerTypeAdapter(PrintRequest.class, new CustomJsonDeserializer());
        Gson gson = gsonBuilder.create();
        PrintRequest printRequest = gson.fromJson(json, PrintRequest.class);
        System.out.println(printRequest.getData());
```

Comment: this solution is not accepted it must be a string: / not strongly type object

Comment: check new solution then

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement a custom deserialiser which converts any `JsonElement` to `String`:

```
class ElementAsStringJsonDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<String> {

    @Override
    public String deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {
        return json.toString();
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
@JsonAdapter(ElementAsStringJsonDeserializer.class)
private String data;
```

See also:

- [GSON: JSON deserialization to variable type (List/String)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55167856/gson-json-deserialization-to-variable-type-list-string/55170378#55170378)