# Android- Json object come as object or array

Tags: android, json, kotlin, serialization, retrofit

I have this json response from the api, and the response can't be change

```
data class Weather (
  val category: String,
  val id: String,
  val meta: Meta
)


data class Meta (
  val id: String,
  val name: String,
  val details: String
)
```

Json respose

```
  { 
   "weather" : {
      "category": "articles",
      "id": "1",
      "meta": {
         "id": "1",
         "name": "The shortest article. Ever.",
         "details": "see"
    },
    "weather" : {
      "category": "articles",
      "id": "2",
      "meta": []
   }
```

If meta is empty, it come with an array but if not empty, it come with object.

Retrofit throws

```
  com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY
```

the api can't be modify so this has to be fix on client end. How can I solve this

Comment: meta can be array or object.. check the json response

Comment: What else can be done except `try` and `catch`?

Comment: try catch does not solve the problem

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Data Class Either Object or Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54995939/data-class-either-object-or-array)

Comment: from where do I slot in the mapper as retrofit does the mapping it self

Comment: like you calling retrofit interface and it throws the error at the point of calling.. so where does the mapper comes in

Comment: adding to the retrofit builder https://stackoverflow.com/a/59513827/4252352

Comment: trying this but  not working.. can you help with sample

Comment: I mean this json is just awful, multiple json objects called with the same key `"weather"` rather than an array of `weather` objects.. aside from your current issue ..choose another weather api.

Comment: I just use the weather as sample case.. I am not calling weather api

Answer (score 0):

You can not  make this possible

meta object must be an object when have value and null when do not have any value, or an array with value when exist and empty when not exist.

meta can not be an array and object in the same time.
this is very bad mistake from who created this response body.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Any** type for meta. and put check at your code level like this.

```
 data class Weather (
      val category: String,
      val id: String,
      val meta: Any
    )

   

     if(meta is Meta) 
        parse it to your Meta object 
        else
        parse it to list
```

Comment: retrofit would have crash before you parse so this won't fly

Comment: if you override setter and then put this check? will it fly?