# Changing two filed names during JSON deserialization in JAVA

Tags: java, json, gson, json-deserialization

I have a json file

```
{"apple" : [
        {
            "first"    : 3,
            "second"    : 5,

        }
      ],
"orange" : [
        {
            "fst"    : 7,
            "snd"    : 8,

        }
      ],
}
```

a helper class for deserialization

```
public class Helper {

    private int num1;

    private int num2;

    public Helper(Helper other) {
        this.num1 = other.num1;
        this.num2 = other.num2;
    }

    public int getNum1() {
        return this.num1;
    }

    public int getNum2() {
        return this.num2;
    }
}
```

A java class for deserialization, which I need to change the JSON keys to be compatible with instance names of the `Helper` class.

```
public class MyDesClass {

    @SerializedName(value = "apple.first", alternate = "apple.num1")
    @SerializedName(value = "apple.seconds", alternate = "apple.num2")
    private final Helper[] apple;

    public MyDesClass(Helper[] apple) {
        this.apple = apple;
    }
    
}
```

And, also inside main.java I have:

```
/* .... */
        Reader f = new FileReader( PATH_TO_THE_JSON_FILE);
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        GameBoard gameBoard = gson.fromJson(f, MyDesClass.class);
/* .... */
```

My question is how can I convert two values (e.g. `first` and `second`) at the same time (e.g. to `num1` and `num2` here) in `MyDesClass`? Currently, I get `SerializedName is not a repeatable annotation type` error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `@SerializedName` in Helper class (and update `MyDesClass` if needed):

```
public class Helper {

    @SerializedName(value = "first" alternate={"num1","fst"})
    private int num1;

    @SerializedName(value = "second" alternate={"num2","snd"})
    private int num2;

    public Helper(Helper other) {
        this.num1 = other.num1;
        this.num2 = other.num2;
    }

    public int getNum1() {
        return this.num1;
    }

    public int getNum2() {
        return this.num2;
    }
}
```

---

To comply with the updated JSON, `MyDesClass` needs to have another field `orange`:

```
public class MyDesClass {

    @SerializedName("apple")
    private final Helper[] apple;

    @SerializedName("orange")
    private final Helper[] orange;

    public MyDesClass(Helper[] apple, Helper[] orange) {
        this.apple = apple;
        this.orange = orange;
    }
// ...    
}
```

Comment: thank you for your solution. However, the JSON key can be variable. sorry, if it was not clear. I extended the JSON file in my example for clarification. So, if deserialization in the `Helper` class is the only option, then is there a way to make the `value` key in `@SerializedName` variable?

Comment: I updated the response for your updated JSON - it requires to have another field `orange`.  However, it's possible that you meant to apply @SerializedName to your `apple` field instead.  Or use map of `<String, List<Helper>>` instead of `MyDesClass` at all.

Comment: thank you very much for your answer, it solved most of my problems. Just, another question here. In my original problem, the first key in JSON is an object and the second key is an array of objects. In the JSON most entries have the order of `key1: Object, key2:[Object1, ...]`. However,  in some cases the order is reverse `key1: [Object1, ...], key2:Object` and it does those entries is not deserialized. Any thoughts on fixing this?

Comment: You may need to check [an answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43868120/gson-deserialize-objects-that-can-be-a-single-object-or-an-array)