# Making Gson work for interface type determined by outer field

Tags: java, android, kotlin, gson, deserialization

Question is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21767485/812919)
but different in that the `type` is not contained within the JSON object being deserialized but is instead contained in the outer level (root).

Like so:

```
{
    "type": "A",
    "myObject" : { <- type is NOT stored in here
        ...
    }
}
```

The intention is to map this JSON object to `Blah`

```
// Code is in Kotlin

interface Foo {
    ...
}

class Bar : Foo { // Map to this if 'type' is A
    ...
}

class Baz : Foo { // Map to this if 'type' is B
    ...
}

class Blah {

    val type : String? = null
    val myObject : Foo? = null
}
```

How do I make `myObject` map to `Bar` if `type` is `A` and `Baz` if `type` is `B`?

Temporarily, I've resorted to reading in the root JSON object manually. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

**EDIT:**

When trying to map the root JSON object to `Blah` using `Gson` `fromJson` method, I get this error: `Unable to invoke no-args constructor for class Foo`. - But this is incorrect anyway, because I need `myObject` to map specifically to either `Baz` or `Bar`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my solution to this. Solution is in Kotlin.

Edit class `Blah`:

```
class Blah {

    val type : String? = null

    @ExcludeOnDeserialization // <- add this
    val myObject : Foo? = null
}
```

Inside some static class:

```
inline fun <T : Annotation>findAnnotatedFields(
    annotation: Class<T>,
    clazz : Class<*>,
    onFind : (Field) -> Unit
){

    for(field in clazz.declaredFields){

        if(field.getAnnotation(annotation)!=null){

            field.isAccessible = true

            onFind(field)
        }
    }
}
```

Create new class and annotation:

```
@Target(AnnotationTarget.FIELD)
annotation class ExcludeOnDeserialization

class GsonExclusionStrategy : ExclusionStrategy {

    override fun shouldSkipClass(clazz: Class<*>?): Boolean {
        return clazz?.getAnnotation(ExcludeOnDeserialization::class.java) != null
    }

    override fun shouldSkipField(f: FieldAttributes?): Boolean {
        return f?.getAnnotation(ExcludeOnDeserialization::class.java) != null
    }
}
```

Read root json object:

```
...

val gson = GsonBuilder()
    .addDeserializationExclusionStrategy(GsonExclusionStrategy())
    .create()

val rootJsonObject = JsonParser().parse(rootJsonObjectAsString)
val blah = gson.fromJson(rootJsonObject, Blah::class.java)

findAnnotatedFields(
    ExcludeOnDeserialization::class.java,
    Blah::class.java
){ foundExcludedField -> // foundExcludedField = 'myObject' declared in 'Blah' class

    val myObjectAsJsonObject
        = rootJsonObject.asJsonObject.getAsJsonObject(foundExcludedField.name)

    when (foundExcludedField.type) {

        Foo::class.java -> {

            when (blah.type) {

                "A" -> {

                    foundExcludedField.set(
                        blah,
                        gson.fromJson(myObjectAsJsonObject, Bar::class.java)
                    )
                }

                "B" -> {

                    foundExcludedField.set(
                        blah,
                        gson.fromJson(myObjectAsJsonObject, Baz::class.java)
                    )
                }

                else -> return null
            }
        }
    }
}

// The root json object has now fully been mapped into 'blah'
```

Inspiration for this solution came from [this article](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/gson-model-annotations-how-to-ignore-fields-with-expose)

Answer (score 1):

This is quite similar as the question you've mentioned.

You can define a deserializer for `Blah` and decide which class should be used.

Code will like below.

```
import com.google.gson.*

interface Foo {
    fun bark()
}

class Bar : Foo { // Map to this if 'type' is A
    override fun bark() {
        print("bar")
    }
}

class Baz : Foo { // Map to this if 'type' is B
    override fun bark() {
        print("baz")
    }
}

class Blah(val type : String? = null, val myObject : Foo? = null) {
    companion object {
        const val TYPE_A = "A"
        const val TYPE_B = "B"
    }
}

class BlahJsonDeserializer: JsonDeserializer<Blah> {
    override fun deserialize(json: JsonElement?, typeOfT: Type?, context: JsonDeserializationContext?): Blah {
        val root = json?.asJsonObject
        val type = root?.get("type")?.asString
        var obj: Foo? = null
        when(type ?: "") {
            Blah.TYPE_A -> { obj = Bar() }
            Blah.TYPE_B -> { obj = Baz() }
        }
        val blah = Blah(type, obj)
        return blah
    }
}

val json = "{'type': 'A', 'myObject': {}}"

val gsonBuilder = GsonBuilder()
gsonBuilder.registerTypeAdapter(Blah::class.java, BlahJsonDeserializer())
val gson = gsonBuilder.create()
val item = gson.fromJson<Blah>(json, Blah::class.java)

item.myObject?.bark() // bar
```

Comment: Thanks, but I avoided doing this way because it meant I had to manually map all of the fields of `Blah` just because one field wasn't being mapped. I was looking for something more semi-automated. I have a solution for this now, will post it later today.

Comment: I've posted my answer. Thanks again.